# QUdpSocket принять пакет отправленный на адрес x.255.255.255

Tags: qt, c++

Не могу прочитать пакет UDP. Ситуация вот какая: есть устройство которое посылает UDP пакеты на адреса 20.255.255.255. WireShark видит эти пакеты, но программой написанной на QT я не могу получить пакет. Получаю пакет так:

```
connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(listPort()));

socket->bind(QHostAddress("20.0.0.1"), 36882);

// Это код слота listPort()
QByteArray datagram;
QHostAddress sender;
quint16 senderPort;

while (socket->hasPendingDatagrams()) {
         datagram.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
         socket->readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size(),&sender, &senderPort);
}
```

Адрес компьютера на котором работает программа написанная на QT 20.0.0.1 (а так же 192.168.1.10).

В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Функция connect из какого класса?

Comment: В общем, причина в том, что это по сути multicast пакет, а Вы хотите читать пакеты конкретно для хоста 20.0.0.1

А вот как это разрулить в замечательном фреймворке qt, я не знаю.

[Пример](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzab6%2Frzab6x2multicast.htm) для обычной работы в \*nix.

==

Каюсь, конечно, ошибся. Все же здесь идет речь о какой-то разновидности broadcast (а не multicast).

Тогда попробуйте [посмотреть тут](http://alas.matf.bg.ac.rs/manuals/lspe/snode=115.html).

Answer (score 1):

```
socket->bind(QHostAddress("20.0.0.1"), 36882,QUdpSocket::ShareAddress);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на [ru.so]! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.